# Portuguese rap song about the rapper refusing a groupie's proposition

Tags: identify-this-song, rap

I am searching for a Portuguese rap song, which was almost over 8 minutes long, and it's from a guy who says a story about himself, that he was approached by a fan to have sex, and he ended up not having sex with her because he didn't have and couldn't buy condoms, so the moral of the story was to not practice unsafe sex in any circumstance.

If I remember well, the name of that song was probably the name of the girl or something like that, but at the moment I can't get myself to remember it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying to find it, I found it just minutes after posting here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mXrllgM9yE

This is the song, "Roleta Russa" from Valete.